# Difference between float and double in php?

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$vad = 1.1;

print gettype($vad);

var_dump($vad);
```

this will output:

```
double
float(1.1)
```

So it is double or float in php?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

There is no difference in PHP. `float`, `double` or `real` are the same datatype.

At the C level, everything is stored as a `double`.
The real size is still platform-dependent.

See the manual for more details:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: sure about that? are there some memory use diffrent about it?

Comment: I have function `function some( float $num){}`, when i use `some(17.23)` it throws **fatal error** some() must be an instance of float, double given,

Comment: @NaveenDA What version of PHP? Prior to PHP 7.0, scalar type hints were not available and would be interpreted as class names instead. That looks like what is going on there.

Comment: just clarifying there's no such datatype `real` in php so far.

Comment: @MuhammadSheraz But there's a `is_real` function, with is an alias of `is_float`... ; )

Comment: @Macmade that's correct, actually I meant we cannot use `(real)` as type hinting, as we know `(double)` and `(float)` are already part of real numbers family.

Answer (score 25):

For PHP, they are the same. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php :

> Floating point numbers (also known as "floats", "doubles", or "real numbers") can be specified using any of the following syntaxes: [...]

The confusing part is why gettype (which you shouldn't use, anyway) returns "double" instead of "float". The answer is https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php:

> " double " (for historical reasons "double" is returned in case of a float , and not simply "float")

Answer (score 11):

As of PHP 7.0.6 on Windows, comparing this command **without** xdebug:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(28.4);'
float(28.4)
```

and **with** xdebug:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(28.4);'
Command line code:1:
double(28.4)
```

Note that this only changes var_dump() output, but not the actual memory management.

This may address some concerns why you see `double` instead of `float` shown in var_dump in some other machines.

Also, with or without xdebug, `gettype` still returns `string(6) "double"`.

Answer (score 7):

In PHP 7.0.14

```
function test(double $a) {
    var_dump($a);
}
test(2.2111);
```

Returns "Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to test() must be an instance of double, float given".

```
function test(float $a) {
    var_dump($a);
}
test(2.2111);
```

Prints 2.2111 to the screen.

Comment: Updated link https://php.net/language.types.declarations

Comment: As the "Type declarations" PHP manual link says, "Aliases for the above scalar types are not supported.". So it's probably best to stick with `float`, which is the official type name and is the most well-supported by the language.