# PHP : is_nan() returning an error

Tags: php

I am simply trying to validate a value using is_nan(). I have my class named validate() which can do this, but I am little bit trying to optimize my code using php's function.

So question is simple.I m using this code and in response I m getting this error. How to remove this error?? What I am doing wrong?? Is there any other way to achieve this goal except preg_match()??

`$discount = "0nbgjgvbngjxk";`

`var_dump(is_nan($discount));`

Result :

```
Error : A non well formed numeric value encountered

bool false
```

Though I am getting the result correct, but how why this error is coming.I m validating for numbers. I m using CodeIgniter, so these errors can be disabled when made live. But I m curious to solve the error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[is_nan](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-nan.php)** takes a float as an argument, but you're passing it a string.

Check out **[is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)** which might be closer to what you want.

Comment: nope. is_numeric validates number with string, which I dont want. I just want numbers.

Comment: and dear I would like to correct you that it expects double type value not float. But hey..it solved my purpose. Thanks for ur response.

Comment: ctype_digit() can also be an option

Comment: I was going off the official documentation that says `is_nan` takes a float, but in PHP doubles and floats are the same. **[Source 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)**, **[Source 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280892/difference-between-float-and-double-in-php)**

Comment: @AakashSahai: `is_numeric()` does that: *Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string* What's the problem with that?

Comment: OZ_ your response is also helpful. But is_numeric is more useful. But your floatval() is also useful, but in other situation.

Comment: Actually stefan and anson I made a mistake while reading the documentation that it returns true when number is found, else false.

Comment: Addition to @Anson answer just to add a bit more clarification, `float` and `double` are same as they both are **Real Numbers** and used to represent **floating point numbers** but different in precision limits that is float is a 32bit IEEE 754 single precision whereas double is a 64bit IEEE 754 double precision