# Magento value becomes a double after being updated

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am making an Extension. In this extension I need to update the grand total.

For instance, if `subtotal=$4` and `discount_amount=$1`, grant total will be `$3`. My problem is that when I perform the calculation, the discounted price becomes double.

```
class PunchTab_Points_Model_Total_Calcdiscount extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract {
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        $session = 2;
        //$session=   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyValue();
        if (isset($session)) {
            $total_discount = $session;
            //Mage::helper('core')->currency($total_discount, true, false);
            $address - > setCalcdiscountAmount((float) $total_discount);
            $address - > setGrandTotal(($address - > getGrandTotal() - $address - > getCalcdiscountAmount()));
            $address - > setBaseGrandTotal(($address - > getBaseGrandTotal() - $address - > getCalcdiscountAmount()));
            return $this;
        }
    }
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
        $amt = $address - > getCalcdiscountAmount();
        if ($address - > getCalcdiscountAmount() > 0) {
            $address - > addTotal(array('code' => $this - > getCode(), 'title' => Mage :: helper('sales') - > __('Reward Discount'), 'value' => -$amt,));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

At this point, the discount/session value becomes double. Please help.

Comment: What's wrong with the value being a double? What do you want it to be? A float? Keep in mind that in php, 'flat', 'double' and 'real' are all the same datatype: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280892/difference-between-float-and-double-in-php

Comment: As in above code i specified total_discount=2.but it shows with double means 4$ shows at front end.

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just do a quick fix e.g;

```
$subtotal = 4
$discount_amount= 1

$temp_discount_amount = $discount_amount % 2

$discount_amount = $temp_discount_amount
```

The ouput will be half of your doubled amount, which will be your expected discount. I know its a simple fix, but should work.

Comment: yes I already resolved this error using same code.Thanks John