# How to convert string to number in php without rounding?

Tags: php

I am retrieving some values stored as string which have up to 15 decimal places. I need to `json_encode`it and pass it on to javascript as numeric value. So I tried `(float)$number`, but the number gets rounded-off in this approach. How else can I convert it to number without any rounding?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php

Comment: Can you post some sample code that demonstrates this?

Comment: @JohnConde well, I can: `print_r(json_decode('{ "test": 3.1234567890123456789 }'));` or `echo json_encode([ 'test' => 3.1234567890123456789 ]);`

Comment: @JohnConde [Yep](http://codepad.org/OhFM2BR0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) library in PHP whenever number precision is important. You may have to enable it inside of your php.ini settings. Search for...

`;extension=php_gmp.dll`

and change it to

`extension=php_gmp.dll`

and then you'll be able to use the GMP objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve those decimals: don't parse it. Any number converted to `float` is [subject to precision loss](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php). Can't you just print the variable as received in JS?

Comment: My problem is, the other coder doing the js, asked me to provide the output as numeric not a string, which it is by default. I also tried double, but....

Comment: @Bluemagica [That's because it's the same in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280892/difference-between-float-and-double-in-php)

Comment: True, but then again that means there is no native way of doing this! sigh!

Comment: @Bluemagica Not natively. Do you need to do calculations with it?

Comment: @Bluemagica Output it as a string.  The javascript doesn't need to know: `echo "var foo = " . $num_as_string . ";";` - the only time you need to actually do the conversion is if you manipulate the number inside the PHP.