# PHP number more than 10 decimal places

Tags: php, floating-accuracy

I have this situation:

```
$a = (double)"8.876543456787654";
echo json_encode(["value" => $a]);
```

It's returning this:

```
{"value":8.8765434567877}
```

And not this, which is the desirable:

```
{"value":8.876543456787654}
```

Note that I can't have this:

```
{"value":"8.876543456787654"}
```

How can I change this precision and cancel the rounding?

Comment: The default precision should be 14 or 16, it can be changed in the php.ini.

Comment: Read this http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.float.php

Comment: Also, using the BCMath extension makes operations on these numbers more accurate: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: The consumer is expecting a double, I take it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set precision higher at runtime

`ini_set("precision", "16");`

Also use `(float)` instead of `(double)`

Comment: arent float and double the same in php?

Comment: Perhaps, just my habit is using `(float)` and i can confirm that'll work.

Comment: I'm having this message: `ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons`. I tested at PHP 5.4, 5.6 and 7 :( ... And I changed to float... :)

Comment: @MattTheNinja https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280892/difference-between-float-and-double-in-php

Comment: Thats right. Thanks!! I was trying to use it in a sandbox hahaha

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Using `(float)` over `(double)` will reduce your file size by the size of 1 character each time you write, thus is likely to have a extremely (but some) performance increase or at minimum use less disk space.

Comment: You do realize that it's just 1 byte you save? There is absolutely no performance gain you could notice or make use of.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It's 1 more byte than you'll have to use.

Comment: Both are doubles on the C implementation. So, absolutely no gain in performance. Zero. Nada. If you are talking about the character in the code (because 'float' has five letters and 'double' has six) you obviously don't have any idea of what performance means.

Comment: Takes longer to process additional (unneeded bits), whilst i said marginal increase i meant marginal, but saying they are exactly equal isn't strictly true....